# Error while deploying play web app into azure cloud

Tags: eclipse, azure, playframework-2.0

Hello i am trying to deploy play application into azure cloud using eclipse and application is working fine in azure storage emulator but while publishing the same in azure i am getting **invalid publish setting file cannot parse the file** error.I deployed code in azure using bit bucket and linked necessary database .When i try to access the URL i get **"you do not have permission to view the file"** message.

have followed this blog https://msopentech.com/blog/2014/09/25/tutorial-running-play-framework-applications-microsoft-azure-cloud-services-2/ still getting the same **invalid publish setting file cannot parse the file** error

can any one show me way.

thank you in advance!!